# Jboss Nested Dependencies for EAR Deployment

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb, ear

I'm working on an EAR that will be deployed to a jboss wildfly server. There is a bunch of common code that gets shared between different projects that the ear depends on. That code gets packaged into a jar and placed into the lib directory of the EAR. So far so good, but as soon as I go to deploy I run into problems. 'Common.jar' has its own set of dependencies which the classloader doesn't seem to be able to locate. When I try to start up my server I get the following error:

```
10:49:08,686 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Person.ear"."Person-web.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Person.ear"."Person-web.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Person-web.war" of deployment "Person.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class com.tura.common.servlet.LogoutServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Person.ear" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/stringtemplate/v4/STWriter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STWriter from [Module "deployment.Person.ear" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 18 more
```

I have tried everything I can think of any nothing seems to help. All of the docs and information I have found so far are for dependencies on jboss modules. How do I set up a dependency on a third-party library nested in a jar?

Comment: Can you deploy the jar itself? If you can't deploy it the then the EAR won't work. A Class not found means that it is not being able to found it the StringTemplate

Comment: Where are the third-party libraries located? If your `common.jar` is in the `EAR/lib` directory the third-party libraries should be there too.